# Create and Update queries are not being executed while installing our extension in the clean typo3 package

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, tx-mask

We have created  Theme Extension  in the following way:

1. Downloaded the extension package from the site package builder(https://sitepackagebuilder.com/new/)
2. Download and installed the TYPO3 V8.7.9 package.
3. Then placed the extension package under the folder typo3conf/ext/ and installed the extension package in the Extension section
4. Installed MASK and Power mail extensions because for implementing template extension we used MASK and PowerMail for form submission.
5. Then placed the theme related templates, styles, Js, typoscript inside the extension folder.
6. MASK content element templates are managed under the folder fileadmin//templates/content, fileadmin//templates/preview and 
   Page content images are managed under the folder fileadmin//images, 
   mask.json file managed under the fileadmin//.
   To achieve the above process, we have modified the mask backend configuration.
7. After implementation of the theme extension, most features work except when we try to install our extension in another clean typo3 package it is not working. 
   In order to solve, we did the following changes:

7.1. Created a new folders Initialisation, Initialisation/Extensions, Initialisation/Files under our extension folder.

7.2. Placed the dependency extension packages into Initialisation/Extensions.

7.3. Placed all the fileadmin files() into Initialisation/Files.

7.4. Modified the file ext_emconf.php to mentioned the extension details and its dependency extensions.

7.5. Placed the exported T3d pagetree file under the folder Initialisation with the name data.t3d

7.6. Added the following code in the file ext_localconf.php, for changing the mask backend configuration

```
<pre>
<code>
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['mask'] = serialize([
'json' => 'typo3conf/ext/key-name/mask.json',
'content' => 'fileadmin/key-name/templates/content/',
'layouts' => 'fileadmin/key-name/templates/content/Layouts/',
'partials' => 'fileadmin/key-name/templates/content/Partials/',
'backend' => 'fileadmin/key-name/templates/backend/',
'layouts_backend' => 'fileadmin/key-name/templates/backend/Layouts/',
'partials_backend' => 'fileadmin/key-name/templates/backend/Partials/',
'preview' => 'fileadmin/key-name/templates/preview/',
]);
</code>
</pre>
```

7.7. If we add a new content element in the mask, a mask will add a new field to the tt_content table and create a new table for storing that content element values. 
Since this theme has too many content elements, we have added the ALTER and CREATE TABLE queries in the ext_tables.sql file.  We have also added the UPDATE and INSERT queries for mask content element values.

Issue: Now the issue is, points 7.6 and 7.7(Create and Update queries are not getting executed) i.e. not working while installing our extension in the clean typo3 package.

Please let me know where we are going wrong.

Many thanks
Regards
Sharmistha

Comment: I sounds like you aim to create a "distribution package", correct? At least steps 7.1 and 7.5 look like that - files, assets and database content that shall be imported when installing an extension.
Can you please mention the changes you've done concerning the SQL ALTER statements and probably paste the SQL error messages here as well?

Comment: Hi Oliver, Thanks so much for your response.  Yes, we are trying to create a distribution Package.  There were no SQL errors. The files ext_tables.sql contains ALTER, CREATE, INSERT and UPDATE queries. ALTER and CREATE queries were executed successfully. INSERT and UPDATE queries  were not.

Comment: @Artur Gaibishel , Thanks for editing my question. Deeply appreciate.

Comment: @OliverHader Do you need to have a look at our Sql queries to analyze the problem. If so let me know, I shall upload the queries. Can you help us in creating a distribution package?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the assumption that a "TYPO3 distribution package" shall be created. The mentioned "site package" approach in the original answer might be superfluous in case no template or backend layout definitions to render the web site frontend are being used.

Creating distribution packages for TYPO3 is briefly documented here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/CreateNewDistribution/Index.html

General file locations of an extension are documented here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html - especially have a look at `ext_tables_static+adt.sql` which would be required to e.g. `INSERT` or `UPDATE`data explicitly.

Concerning SQL declarations and adjustments the following explanations are important:

- `ext_tables.sql` only supports declaration of tables, thus only `CREATE` is supported and executed - modifications like `UPDATE` or `INSERT` are not considered
- every time an extension gets installed (or the database analyzer in the TYPO3 install tool is invoked manually) the current database schema is compared to the definitions in `ext_table.sql` files and adjusted (altered) in case there are differences - all `ext_table.sql` files of installed extensions are considered and merged at this step
- `ALTER TABLE` statements are not evaluated in `ext_table.sql` - in case you want to adjust field declarations, use and additional `CREATE` statement containing new fields or the types to be altered - e.g. `ext:felogin` of the TYPO3 core is altering the existing tables `fe_groups` and `fe_users` in https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7/typo3/sysext/felogin/ext_tables.sql
- specific `INSERT` statements have to be part of the file `ext_tables_static+adt.sql`, see `ext:extensionmanager` of the TYPO3 core making use of that feature in https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7/typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/ext_tables_static%2Badt.sql
- imports in a distribution package should basically happen using the file `Initialisation/data.t3d` which can be created using the "Import/Export Module" as being part of the TYPO3 core package

Hope that helps. In case there are further questions, please provide error messages or warnings and describe what you wanted to achieve in particular. Thx

Comment: Thanks so so so much. I shall check with the instructions given by you and get back ASAP. Truly appreciate your efforts. Regards Sharmistha

Comment: Hi Oliver @Oliver Hader. A BIG THANKS to your suggestion. Issue 7.7 is working. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi Oliver  the remaining issue is 7.6. Added the following code in the file ext_localconf.php, for changing the mask backend configuration
We are not able to solve this issue.
Can you please guide us? Please note, this template will be our contribution to the TYPO3 community, since we found that there is a real dearth  of good templates. Please help us . Regards Sharmistha

Comment: I'm not much into configuration of 3rd party extension `mask`. Maybe you'll find some answers in this blog post https://typo3worx.eu/2016/11/typo3-custom-content-elements-made-easy/ - especially look for `mask_export`.

Comment: Thanks so much Oliver!. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: Hey Oliver, the link you gave was really useful. Thanks so much.!!